# Disable & enable auto-correct dynamically in the same html text area

Tags: uiwebview, autocomplete, webview, autocorrect

I'm trying to build a twitter like autocomplete and am having trouble disabling autocorrect dynamically.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is have `auto-correct="off"` when someone hits `#` and `auto-correct="on"` when they tap either the space bar or an item on the autocomplete list I provide.

I've attempted to use jquery `attr` but as one would suspect, to no avail.

`@textarea.attr("autocorrect", "on")`

Any suggestions for how I could disable autocorrect while someone is using autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't much of an answer as it is a mystery but after switching to AngularJS, I no longer needed to disable auto-correct dynamically, somehow something changed and I benefited. Go AngularJS!